# How to get the highest tf-idf values of words for each class after using tfidf.vectorizer

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, nlp, tokenize

So I have a dataset with 3 label: Soccer, Music and Movies
I used tfidf.vectorizer and then logistic regression to train my model, now I want to get a list of the 5 words that have the highest tfidf for each label.  (5 highest for soccer, 5 for Music ... )
I couldn't find a way to get them.

This is the code that I have

```
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
y = le.fit_transform(data["Label"])
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer = 'word')
X = tfidf.fit_transform(data["text"])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.1)
lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
lr.score(X_test,y_test)
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how TFIDF works. The vectorizer computes word-scores per document, not category.

To get scores per document, use

```py
X.nonzero()
```

If you want to get TFIDF scores per category, then I would recommend pooling all the texts from the same category together into a single document and running TF-IDF again.